# Laravel Send or Queue Mail depending on config setting

Tags: laravel

I am looking for a neat way to send or queue email depending on a config setting.

Right now I am having to do something like this everytime I send an email

```
$mailContent = new AccountNotification($account);
$mailObject = Mail::to($email);
if(config('app.queueemail')){
   $mailObject->queue($mailContent);
} else {
   $mailObject->send($mailContent);
}
```

There has to be a simpler way to do this so I don't have to repeat this code each time I want to send an email.

Comment: You could extend the Mail class. Put in a custom `send` function that checks the config and uses the parent class's send/queue functions accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @ceejayoz's comment, a simpler way could also be to use a global Helper function.

For example, you could have a `send_email()` global function that will send/queue email depending on your app's configuration.

```
if ( ! function_exists('send_email')) {
    /**
    * Sends or queues email
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    function send_email($mailer, $content)
    {
        return config('app.queueemail')
            ? $mailer->queue($content)
            : $mailer->send($content); 
    }
}
```

To use it you would do:

```
send_email($mailer, $content);
```